# Tkinter Treeview Empty Row

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Is there a way to create an empty row in a Treeview for Tkinter. A row that other rows can be moved to?

Currently I have a treeview where rows can be moved.  When moved currently it switches the places of all the other rows to fill the gap.  I want an area where I can move a row to without affecting the other rows?

Comment: Can you add an example? What kind of treeview are you using? In regular a `ttk.Treeview`, the user cannot move rows around. Your question is too vague at the moment, it is always better to show what you have tried so far. You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question.

Comment: You could just create a row with no values

Comment: Creating blanks worked thanks!